# How to max(date) and use the in feature in sql server in one query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table such as this

```
id   color  shade   date
---  ----   -----   -----
1    red    dark    01/01/1990
2    red    light   09/16/2013
3    green  light   08/15/2010
4    green  dark    09/18/2012
5    maroon dark    08/20/2013
6    white  dark    08/31/2013
7    white  light   08/30/2012
8    purple light   08/20/2010
```

I wanted entries for each color with the latest date. So I tried doing:

```
select id, color, shade, max(date) from mytable;
```

This didn't work and gave me error:

```
is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate 
function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Alright, so I added it in the `Group By` as suggested by the error

```
select id, color, shade, max(date) from mutable
Group by id, color, shade
```

This gave me the desired results.

**Question**

Now, I wanted the same query as above repeated only for certain colors. For example I only wanted to see red and green ones.

So I did:

```
select id, color, shade, max(date) from mutable
Where color in ('red', 'green')
Group by id, color, shade;
```

However, this does not give me the correct number of results because I guess they are being grouped by `shade`.

What is the best way to fetch my desired results? Basically I want `max date` out of the two instances of same thing and further out of the table only want certain colors.

Comment: when you say same thing, you mean same color? And your desired output is "1,red,light,09/16/2013" and "4,green,dark,09/18/2012" ?

Answer (score 2):

In standard SQL any of the following queries solve the issue:

**Option 1**

```
SELECT t1.* FROM t t1
LEFT JOIN t t2
ON t1.color = t2.color AND t1.shade = t2.shade AND t1.date < t2.date
WHERE t2.date IS NULL
```

**Option 2**

```
SELECT t1.* FROM t t1
JOIN (
  SELECT color, shade, max(date) date FROM t
  GROUP BY color, shade
) t2
ON t1.color = t2.color AND t1.shade = t2.shade AND t1.date = t2.date
```

In your example data, all the result should be returned, so it doesn't make much sense to operate on it. I've slightly changed it into this:

```
| ID | COLOR | SHADE |       DATE |
|----|-------|-------|------------|
|  1 |   red |  dark | 1990-01-01 |
|  2 |   red |  dark | 2013-09-16 |
|  3 | green | light | 2010-08-15 |
|  4 | green |  dark | 2012-09-18 |
|  5 | green |  dark | 2013-08-20 |
|  6 | white |  dark | 2013-08-31 |
|  7 | white | light | 2012-08-30 |
|  8 | white | light | 2010-08-20 |
```

The output of the queries would be:

```
| ID | COLOR | SHADE |       DATE |
|----|-------|-------|------------|
|  2 |   red |  dark | 2013-09-16 |
|  3 | green | light | 2010-08-15 |
|  5 | green |  dark | 2013-08-20 |
|  6 | white |  dark | 2013-08-31 |
|  7 | white | light | 2012-08-30 |
```

Make sure you apply the appropriate orderings.

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/888be/1).

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to think about this is by first creating a query that gives you the latest date for each colour:

```
select color, max([date]) as maxdate
from mytable
group by color;
```

Then by joining this query with a simple select query that just retrieves all rows from your original table:

```
select t.[id], t.color, t.shade, sq.maxdate
from mytable as t
inner join (
  select color, max([date]) as maxdate
  from mytable
  group by color
) as sq
on (t.color = sq.color);
```

Then, to restrict the results to only certain colours, just add on your `where` clause at the end of the query:

```
where color in ('red', 'green');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.* FROM t t1
JOIN 
(
  SELECT color, MAX([date]) [date] FROM t
  WHERE color IN ('red', 'green')
  GROUP BY color
) t2
ON t1.color = t2.color AND t1.date = t2.date
ORDER BY ID
```

**OUTPUT**

```
id  color   shade   date
2   red     light   2013-09-16
5   green   dark    2013-08-20
```

OR

```
SELECT id, color, shade, [date]
FROM 
(
  SELECT *,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY color ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS sno
  FROM t
  WHERE color IN ('red', 'green')
) tt
WHERE sno = 1
ORDER BY ID
```

**OUTPUT**

```
id  color   shade   date
2   red     light   2013-09-16
5   green   dark    2013-08-20
```

OR

```
SELECT id, color, shade, [date]
FROM 
(
  SELECT *,
        MAX([date]) OVER (PARTITION BY color) AS maxdate
  FROM t
  WHERE color IN ('red', 'green')
) tt
WHERE [date] = maxdate
ORDER BY ID
```

**OUTPUT**

```
id  color   shade   date
2   red     light   2013-09-16
5   green   dark    2013-08-20
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, color, shade, max(date) over() AS m_date from mutable
```

OVER CLAUSE used IN analyze functions

Comment: what does `over()` achieve?

Comment: if your version SQL SERVER >= 2005 U may use OVER clause)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with window/ranking functions.  Here is an example with `row_number()`:

```
select id, color, shade, "date"
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by color order by "date" desc) as seqnum
      from mytable
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```