# Update where column has highest value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a simple "undo"-system for a table with the following structure:

```
id    element    position    start_date    end_date
1       1          23        01/01/2015    05/01/2015
2       2          36        01/01/2015    NULL
3       1          17        05/01/2015    NULL
```

So, when a new action is added for an existing element, it adds a new row with the new position and the current date, and changes the end_date of the previous row of that element to the current date.

Now, to undo this, I delete the row of the element where there is no end_date defined (this is the latest action for that element), but then I have to change the end_date of the previous row to `null`.

So, in pseudolanguage, the query needed would be:

```
UPDATE [table] SET end_date = NULL
WHERE element = 1
  AND start_date = 'highest_start_date_to_be_found_of_this_element'
```

Question: what to type instead of `highest_start_date_to_be_found_of_this_element` to make it work?

Comment: try using max([date]) ..this may help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839486/how-to-maxdate-and-use-the-in-feature-in-sql-server-in-one-query

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That should give you the latest start_date to every entry which has the same value in element like the defined value in update statement.
So you need to change it only at one place.

```
UPDATE [table] t SET t.end_date = NULL WHERE t.element = 1 AND t.start_date = (select max(sub.start_date) from [table] sub where sub.element = t.element)
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use a subquery with `TOP` and `ORDER BY`:

```
update t
    set end_date = NULL
    from (select top 1 t.*
          from table t
          order by start_date desc
         );
```

This will update only one row.  If you want all rows with the maximum start date, then use `with ties` in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(id int, start_date date)

INSERT INTO #temp(id, start_date) 
VALUES(1,GETDATE()),(2,DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE())),(1,DATEADD(day,+3,GETDATE()))

SELECT *
FROM #temp

-- your part
UPDATE t
SET start_date = m.maxDate
FROM #temp t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, MAX(start_date) as maxDate
    FROM #temp 
    GROUP BY id
) m
    ON t.id = m.id

SELECT *
FROM #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
```